# how to change the position of boxes?

Tags: html, css

this is my code, i want to create box in box in css and html

but when i made it,i couldn't move the boxes, i need a margin from top to put the boxes in the center of the box or moving them in to the main box,how can i do this?

code:

```
<html >
    <head>
        <style>
            ui {
                background-color:red;
                padding:100px 100px;
            }

            div1{
                background-color:white;
                padding:50px 50px;
            }

            div2{
                background-color:yellow;
                padding:50px 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ui>
            <div1>hello</div1>
            <div2>bye</div2>
        </ui>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Vucko don't worry it is valid in HTML5, but the main question is, what is the code actually supposed to do!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: @Vucko: JSF/Facelets, see http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-composition.html

Comment: @Vucko this is just  a name!

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140">
<p>Because the image has a z-index of -1, it will be placed behind the text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Produces: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex